# Use no tabs in Gedit

Tags: gedit, tabs

How to force Gedit always, any time, in any place open new doc in a new window?
And never, nowhere open it in a new tab?

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter `.desktop` shortcut:

- Replace `gedit %U` with `gedit -s %u`.
- Disable DBus activation.

The command line to do both modifications at once:

`$ sed "s/\(Exec=gedit \)%U$/\1-s %u/;s/\(DBusActivatable=\).*/\1false/" /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.gedit.desktop | sudo tee /usr/local/share/applications/org.gnome.gedit.desktop`