# Gedit tabs preference

Tags: gedit, tabs

As these two questions show:

- [Use no tabs in Gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999443/use-no-tabs-in-gedit)
- [gedit - open files in new tabs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116464/gedit-open-files-in-new-tabs)

there is a need to control gedit tabs behavior when opening a file.

For example, always force to open in new window or always force to open in new tab, even if it is in an other workspace.

Is there a way to access this parameter somewhere?

NB: by "tabs" I mean the element of graphical interface allowing to edit multiple files in the same window as shown in the picture below

[image]

Comment: I'm using Gnome on multiple Ubuntu / non-Ubuntu OS.

Comment: That does not answer the question. Let's say I only use Ubuntu 20.04. The question is still about this gedit parameter.

Comment: Gedit DOES open multiple documents, into different tabs, in the same window. Doesn't yours?

Comment: It depends on the context. If there is a gedit window in the same workspace, it does open a tab in the window, otherwise, it opens a new window. The question is about setting the preference: always open in tab / never open in tab.

Comment: I just tried this exact sequence on my 21.04 system. I opened two .txt docs into Gedit, and both opened in new tabs in the same window. Then I moved the entire Gedit window to a different workspace, then opened a third .txt document, and it opened into a new third tab in the Gedit window in the other workspace. Do you have some special theme, gnome-extension, or non-stock Ubuntu mod installed?

Comment: So you mean gedit opened the file in an existing window located in an other workspace? I never saw this behavior. And my Ubuntu is pretty much untouched.

Comment: Log into a different user account, create one if you don't have one, and retry Gedit there and see if you have the same results. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @HugoTrentesaux please see my answer that attempts to achieve the desired end functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement for certain works I do and need to open two text files in two different windows - one on laptop screen and the other on the extended screen. I couldn't find any setting to force using or not using tab for new file, perhaps it will be available in future. But for the time being I created a nautilus script to achieve the desired functionality.

Created a file named "Gedit-New-Window" in the nautilus scripts folder, added the required command and assigned executable permission to it. Here's how in terminal:

```
cd ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
nano Gedit-New-Window
#!/bin/sh
gedit --new-window $@
^O
^X
chmod +x Gedit-New-Window
```

> For new Ubuntu/Linux users unfamiliar with nano: ^O (Ctrl + o) and ^X
> (Ctrl + x) above are nano keyboard commands to write out the file and
> exit.

Now, whenever a file needs to be opened in a Gedit new window, I right-click on the file in nautilus, click on "Scripts" in the context-menu, then click on "Gedit-New-Window" that shows as one of the options.